# detect the app was reopened by the Notification Center or through his Icon while he was returning from the Background? UIApplicationStateBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I would like a help, is there any way to detect the app was **reopened** by the Notification Center or through his Icon while he was returning from the Background?  `UIApplicationStateBackground`

When the app is closed I can see the difference through  `launchoptions` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *pushNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

        if (pushNotification) {
        //Tapped Notification when app is inactive
        }
}
```

But when the app come from background I don't know if they touched the app icon or the notification.

Answer (score 1):

check the `options` object in the [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:). Checking key's are described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys)

Comment: when app is reopened `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is not called. I used `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{
    
}`

Comment: store a `BOOL` flag, set it in the `application handleActionWithIdentifier` method. then take necessary action in `
- applicationDidBecomeActive:`. dont forget the clear the flag at the end of the  `
- applicationDidBecomeActive:`

Comment: Thanks Ratul, but one problem for is the support to iOS 7, and  `application handleActionWithIdentifier` is only iOS 8+

Comment: then use the comment #2 strategy with this [- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:) method. hope you get benefitted by it.

Comment: does the last comment match your requirement ?